# Float Bootstrap navbar links to the left on mobile and right on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar has 4 links all floating to the right. I used `.pull-right` to make it work. On mobile, I would like every link to move to the left except for my active link. I want my active link to stay right on all devices.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this. Are there any classes within Bootstrap that can help with this or do I need to create a custom class for pulling the 3 links left on mobile?

HTML

```
<!-- Fixed Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>       
        </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Summit</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="login.html">Client Login</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

    </div> <!-- end container -->
</nav> <!-- end navbar navbar-custom -->
```

CSS

```
/*======= navbar ========*/
.navbar {
    opacity: 0.95;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.95;
    -moz-opacity: 0.95;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95); /* internet explorer */
}

#navbar > ul.nav a:hover {
    color: #50b948; /*TD Green*/
}

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem; /*14px*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #5e5e5e;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background: #50b948; 
    color: #FAFAFA; 
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background: #FAFAFA;

    -webkit-box-shadow: .5px .5px 4px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: .5px .5px 4px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.75);
    box-shadow: .5px .5px 4px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.75);
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ccc; /*btn border-color*/
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ddd; /*btn color on hover*/
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-custom .navbar-form {
    border-color: #ccc; /*collapsed bottom border color*/
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #555;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
      color: #777;
}
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
      color: #333;
      background-color: transparent;
}
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
      color: #555;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
      color: #ccc;
      background-color: transparent;
  }
}
  .navbar-custom .navbar-link {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-custom .btn-link {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-custom .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-custom .btn-link:focus {
    color: #333;
}
.navbar-custom .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-custom .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-custom .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-custom .btn-link:focus {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: To answer your "Can Bootstrap already do this" portion; no.  Bootstrap has nothing like `.pull-left-xs`.  Your easiest approach would likely be a `@media` declaration that overrides the `float`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here will be to utilize the classes Bootstrap already adds for mobile and non-mobile.

Your div:

`navbar-collapse collapse`

Becomes:

`navbar-collapse collapse in`

When the slide down menu is opened on mobile. This means if your CSS applies to the class `.navbar-collapse.in` it will only apply to the open menu on mobile.

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Additionally, Bootstrap v4.0 (currently available but in alpha) contains the classes `.pull-xs-left` and `.pull-sm-right`, presumably for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I re-read the docs on Boootstrap site and the answer is to use navbar-right. '.navbar-right' will pull the nav on larger scale to the right but move it back to the left on mobile which makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use '.navbar-right'. Specifically designed to move the nav to the right on desktop, but will move links back to the left when on mobile view.

Comment: Is there any way to keep things to the right even on mobile?